# URL Parameter to open page in existing window

Tags: html, url, browser

I'm using a framework that allows me to create a "link" in a page, but when I click the link, it opens a new browser window.  Is there a parameter I can put in the URL that will tell the page to open in the existing window rather than opening a new one?

Comment: This depends on how your framework creates links. No information on this has been provided, so it is impossible to answer this question.

Comment: As said above. More info if possible please. Shot in the dark would be to ask if you can change the `target` attribute of the `<a>`? (assuming that's what you mean with the link) http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Comment: the framework allows me to specify a link...i.e. "http://www.google.com".  When I click the link, it navigates to it in a new window/tab.  I'd like to know if there's a way to pass something in the URL that directs the browser to open the link in the same page.  i.e. "http://www.google.com&StayHere=true".  I dont have the ability to modify the html or use javascript because I'm not in control of the rendering of the page containing the links.

Comment: @Puuskis Please refer to mdn instead. See http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I dont have the ability to modify the html or use javascript because I'm not in control of the rendering of the page containing the links

Then you have no control over anything that would influence which window the link is opened in.

Comment: Thats what I figured...but thought I'd ask.  Thanks